# Как в Outlook 2013 сделать автоматическое добавление себя в копию?

Tags: email, office, outlook

Есть MS Outlook 2013 (английский). Как сделать так, чтобы для любого отправляемого мной письма мой адрес был автоматически добавлен в копию или скрытую копию?

PS: Нагуглил что-то со скриншотами для 2010, но что-то не могу найти нужные пункты в 2013.

Comment: такая [статья](https://www.ablebits.com/outlook-blind-carbon-copy-bcc-email-addins/) не подходит? найдена по строке поиска *outlook 2013 auto bcc*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет, использование расширения за 30 долларов не подходит.

Comment: не разглядел. неужели всё так сложно? это ж элементарная функция любого полноценного почтового клиента. может быть, имеет смысл воспользоваться другим клиентом?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я вот такое нашёл http://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/de89f9cf-308c-4998-b28b-6d4e2d9095bd но что-то не пойму, где в 2013 взять такой диалог. Диалог правил что-то совсем на это не похож. А, всё. Я понял, какое место не заметил. Если получится, потом напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Лента: Home → Rules (в секции Move).
2. Manage Rules & Alerts...
3. E-mail Rules → New Rule...
4. Секция Start from blank rule → Apply rule on messages I send
5. Шаг Select condition(s) - ничего не отмечать
6. Подтвердить своё желание применить ко всем
7. Шаг Select action(s) → Cc the message to people or public group
8. Внизу щёлкнуть ссылку people or public group и добавить себя
9. Шаг Select exceptions - ничего не отмечать
10. Шаг Finish rule setup - задать имя правила
11. Finish

Comment: честь *ms/outlook-а* спасена!